# writing a mathematical formula in sql

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

Using the following sql query :

```
Select count(*) as Totaladmit From v_dbPatientAdmissions where AdmitDate > '2017-01-01' and AdmitDate <'2017-12-30' and PatientType = 2
Select count(*) as TotalDischarge From v_dbPatientAdmissions where DischargeDate > '2017-01-01' and DischargeDate <'2017-012-30' and PatientType = 2
select count(*) as totalIP from v_dbPatientAdmissions where PatientType=2 and DischargeDate is null 
select count (BedName) as Bedcount from V_Beds
```

We get the following output:

```
TotalAdmit
66668

TotalDischarge
6651

TotalIP
91

BedCount
174
```

I want to write a mathematical formula that does the following : 
[image]

In order to crate a crystal report that returns only one value (Rate), also for the Totaladmit and TotalDischarge i want to apply a condition the excludes the records that shares the same AdmitDate and DischargeDate.

Comment: Is your third query correct - is there not a chance some of these may have been admitted in 2017 and therefore double counted?

Comment: Well, i will do this  calculation like this - first i will run all count query individually and take the result in one variable for exa. `Select @Totaladmit = count(*)  From v_dbPatientAdmissions where AdmitDate > '2017-01-01' and AdmitDate <'2017-12-30' and PatientType = 2` and then run your formula like this - `SELECT ( (@TotalIp + @Totaladmit - @TotalDischarge ) / @BedCount ) * 100.0`. That's it. try it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have different condition on your select, so common group by with `WHERE` will not work.

You can try like following. This will be the simplest solution.

```
SELECT ( ( TotalIp + Totaladmit - TotalDischarge ) / BedCount ) * 100 AS 
       [Output] 
FROM   (SELECT (SELECT Count(*) 
                From   v_dbPatientAdmissions 
                where  AdmitDate > '2017-01-01' 
                       and AdmitDate < '2017-12-30' 
                       and PatientType = 2)       as Totaladmit, 
               (SELECT Count(*) 
                From   v_dbPatientAdmissions 
                where  DischargeDate > '2017-01-01' 
                       and DischargeDate < '2017-12-30' 
                       and PatientType = 2)       as TotalDischarge, 
               (SELECT Count(*) 
                from   v_dbPatientAdmissions 
                where  PatientType = 2 
                       and DischargeDate is null) as TotalIp, 
               (SELECT Count (BedName) 
                from   V_Beds)                    AS Bedcount) T
```

Apart from this, you can also use `CROSS APPLY` for doing the same thing.

Comment: the TotalIp is not being recgnized so i changed the "C" to TotalIp, but the value it returned was 0 ,

Comment: First do just the select, instead of calculation like SELECT TotalIp , Totaladmit , TotalDischarge ,BedCount and then check your values.

Comment: they give values but when executing the full query i still get a '0'

Comment: fixed, i had to move the 100 in the beginning of the formula '100*( ( TotalIp + Totaladmit - TotalDischarge ) / BedCount )  ', but I'm still trying to figure out how to use the cast function with a where condition that excludes the records that shares the same date AdmitDay=DischargeDate

Comment: What do you mean by cast?

Comment: You can always use CAST(TotalIp AS DECIMAL(15,2))

Comment: for example cast(AdmitDate as Date) and cast(DischargeDate as Date) , and then i want to compare them using Where AdmitDate!=DischargeDate to exclude the records that share the same date for  all TotalIp,Totaladmit and TotalDischarge, how can i add them to the query ?

Comment: DischargeDate <'2017-012-30' this is not correct date. If you want to compare date part only you can always do CAST(DATE1 AS DATE) <> CAST(DATE2 AS DATE). What problem you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-

```
SELECT
    ( ( 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PatientType=2 and DischargeDate is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER()
     + SUM(CASE WHEN AdmitDate > '2017-01-01' and AdmitDate <'2017-12-30' and PatientType = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER() )
     - (SUM(CASE WHEN DischargeDate > '2017-01-01' and DischargeDate <'2017-012-30' and PatientType = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER() )
     ) * 100.0 / ( select COUNT(BedName) OVER() from V_Beds )
FROM v_dbPatientAdmissions
```

Comment: when excuting the query i get an error saying  "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.", also   i want to apply a condition the excludes the records that shares the same AdmitDate and DischargeDate.

Comment: I hv update the solution please try now. Which condition u want to add.

Comment: when executing the query i get another error saying "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
 "

Comment: and the condition i need to apply is :                                                          if the AdmitDate=DischargeDate  then we want to exclude these records, also since AdmitDate and DichargeDate are in Datetime format we will need to convert it to date first , because i only want to exclude the records that share the same date

Comment: @pawan-kumar Why the over() clause?

Answer (score 0):

I would bypass the complication of same day discharge by including them in the calculation 
for example

```
drop table t
go
create table t(patientid int, admitdate date, dischargedate date)
create table b(bedname varchar(1))
go
truncate table t
insert into t values (1,'2017-01-01','2017-01-01'),(1,'2017-02-01',null),(2,'2017-01-01','2017-02-01'),
(3,'2016-01-01','2017-01-01'),(4,'2016-01-01',null)

insert into b values ('a'),('b')

select (admittednull + (admitted - discharged - sameday)) / beds * 100 as calulatedratio
from
(
select sum(case when year(admitdate) = 2017 then 1 else 0 end) as admitted,
        sum(case when year(dischargedate) = 2017 then 1 else 0 end) as discharged,
        sum(case when year(admitdate) <> 2017 and dischargedate is null then 1 else 0 end) as admittednull,
        (select count(*) from b) beds,
        sum(case when year(admitdate) = 2017 and year(dischargedate) = 2017 and admitdate = dischargedate then 1 else 0 end) sameday
from t
) s
```

As it happens this returns a value of 0.

Comment: will that effect the Database ? since I'm not allowed to do so all i can do is use a query to create a report

Comment: I assume you are talking about the suggested change to the query if so then no, Selects are read only queries. You would need an insert,update or delete to affect the db.